# AngularJS search with multiple textboxes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to do a search of a table with multiple textboxes.  The user should be able to enter address in the address box and search the table my address, and enter city in the city search box and search the table by city.  I can't get it to work, I'm getting the error message: Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Here's my html:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Address
            </th>
            <th>
                City
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input ng-model="vm.search_address" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input ng-model="vm.search_city" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="search in searchesFound = ( vm.searches | filter: {address: search_address, city: search_city})">
            <td>
                {{ search.address }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ search.city }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

ANd here's my controller:

```
(function () {   

angular.module('crm.ma')        
    .controller('AdvancedSearchCtrl', function () {
        var vm = this;

        vm.search_address = "";
        vm.search_city = "";


        vm.searchs = [
            {
                address: '202 This St',
                city : 'Columbus'
            },
            {
                address: '205 That St',
                city: 'Dayton'
            }
        ]

    });
})();
```

Any clues on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try removing the curly braces?
        <tr ng-repeat="search in searchesFound = ( vm.searches | filter: address: search_address, city: search_city)">

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez that gives me the error message Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ',' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 64 of the expression [searchesFound = ( vm.searches | filter: address: search_address, city: search_city)] starting at [, city: search_city)].

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the vm object. In your filter **vm.search_city** and **vm.search_address** should be used:

```
<tr ng-repeat="search in vm.searchs | filter: {address: vm.search_address, city: vm.search_city}">
```

Comment: Hi Benoit.  Sorry it took me so long to get back to this, but this did not correct the problem.  I still don't get any results.  Is there maybe something else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Getting the error message 
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ',' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 67 of the expression [searchesFound = ( vm.searches | filter: address: vm.search_address, city: vm.search_city)] starting at [, city: vm.search_city)].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$parse/syntax?p0=%2C&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B)%5D&p2=67&p3=searchesFound%20%3D%20(%20vm.searches%20%7CNaNilter%3A%20address%3A%20vm.search_address%2C%city%3A%20vm.search_city)&p4=%2C%city%3A%20vm.search_city)

Comment: You're right, I answered too quickly. The right syntax should be "search in vm.searchs | filter: {address: vm.search_address, city: vm.search_city}"

Answer (score 0):

Look this:

```js
var app = angular.module('ngApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.smartphones = [
        {brand: 'Apple', model: 'iPhone 4S', price: '999'},
        {brand: 'Samsung', model: 'SIII', price: '888' },
        {brand: 'LG', model: 'Optimus', price: '777'},
        {brand: 'htc', model: 'Desire', price: '666'},
        {brand: 'Nokia', model: 'N9', price: '555'}
    ];
    
    $scope.search = function(){
        angular.forEach($scope.smartphones, function(value, key) {
            var brand = ($scope.queryBrand? $scope.queryBrand.toLowerCase():' ');
            var model = ($scope.queryModel? $scope.queryModel.toLowerCase():' ');
           
            value.show = (value.brand.toLowerCase().indexOf(brand) > -1 || 
                          value.model.toLowerCase().indexOf(model) > -1 || (brand == ' ' && model == ' '));
            
             console.log(!brand && !model)
        });
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div ng-app="ngApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">

<input class="span4 pull-right" type="text" placeholder="Filter by brand" ng-model="queryBrand" ng-change="search()">
<input class="span4 pull-right" type="text" placeholder="Filter by model" ng-model="queryModel" ng-change="search()">

<div class="row"> 
    <table id="results" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="smartphone in smartphones" ng-init="smartphone.show=true" ng-show="smartphone.show">
            <td id="brand">{{smartphone.brand}}</td>
            <td id="model">{{smartphone.model}}</td>
            <td id="price">{{smartphone.price | currency}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
  </div>
```